# How to format a string for different language with different arguments in Android?

Tags: android

I have two string resources. The first one in main\values is in English and doesn't have a string argument:

```
<string name="example">Have a good day!</string>
```

But in French, under values-fr, we have a different phrase with one argument, like so:

```
<string name="example">Bonne journée M. %1$s!</string>
```

How should I use the resource string formatter? This works, but it doesn't seem right (and it generates a lint warning):

```
textView.setText(getString(R.string.example, name));
```

---

The lint warning is "StringFormatInvalid" and the description is "Format string '`example`' is not a valid format string so it should not be passed to `String.format`"

Comment: Please edit the question and display your lint warning

Comment: Here is the official lint rule:

Invalid format string  If a string contains a '%' character, then the string may be a formatting string which will be passed to String.format from Java code to replace each '%' occurrence with specific values.  This lint warning checks for two related problems: (1) Formatting strings that are invalid, meaning that String.format will throw exceptions at runtime when attempting to use the format string. (2) Strings containing '%' that are not formatting strings getting passed to a String.format call. In this case the '%' will need to be escaped as '%%'.

Comment: NOTE: Not all Strings which look like formatting strings are intended for use by String.format; for example, they may contain date formats intended for android.text.format.Time#format(). Lint cannot always figure out that a String is a date format, so you may get false warnings in those scenarios. See the suppress help topic for information on how to suppress errors in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your approach. The formatter works perfectly even if there are too many arguments. The leftover arguments just get dropped.

Lint warnings are there to indicate possible unintended errors in the code. But if you know what you are doing you just may suppress the warning by adding the `@SuppressLint("StringFormatMatches")` annotation to the enclosing method or class.

Comment: I decided to add the suppress warning in the english XML file

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String.format(String args, Object...args) method. More info. at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29

Answer (score 0):

it's explained here !
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-localization-at-runtime/
you must create custom Locale and set new config to getResource